# how to append a bytes in a Postgres bytea array

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, append, bytea

I have an account table database which stores username, email, password and images[]. And what I want to do that every time they share a picture the picture bytes should append in images type bytea[]. I used several methods but always ends up with an error what is the solution?

```
bytea = []

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open(os.path.join('image\\Image.png'), 'rb') as file:
    image = file.read()
    #bytea.append(image)

insert_info = f"SELECT array_append(images, {image}) WHERE id = 7"


my_cursor.execute(insert_info)
mydb.commit()
```

The error

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: SELECT account array_append(images, b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\...
```

Comment: You're `SELECT`ing not `INSERT`ing or `UPDATE`ing;    This >>>`insert_info = f"SELECT array_append(images, {image}) WHERE id = 7"`  should be this  >>>`insert_info = f"UPDATE array_append(images, {image}) WHERE id = 7"`

Comment: Its hits me with an error `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("`

Answer (score 1):

you must write select rather than insert :

```
bytea = []

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open(os.path.join('image\\Image.png'), 'rb') as file:
    image = file.read()
    bytea.append(image)

insert_info = f"insert array_append(images, {image}) WHERE id = 7"


my_cursor.execute(insert_info)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: I used the script above but still here is the error ```psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "array_append"
LINE 1: INSERT array_append(images, 'b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00...```